# Error: Unable to resolve dependency for compileClasspath using transform ExtractAarTransform

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0, gradlew

For a helping lib I use, I recently get:

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Failed to transform file 'mylib-release.aar' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform
>   ExtractAarTransform

and then on gradle console:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':demo:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
> > Failed to transform file 'mylib-release.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform
> >     ExtractAarTransform
> >     java.io.FileNotFoundException: mylib-release.aar (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)

It was working last week, unfortunately I forgot what changed

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was the missing .aar file (or files, depending on how many buildtypes you have), as @JBTPublic pointed out.

So how did I fix it? Well, **you need to generate it by yourself**. At least for me, Android Studio doesn't generate it by itself. I had imported an Android library onto my project, and it was working perfectly well in a Linux environment. But I forgot that I needed to generate the AAR file before running my Android app.

To generate the AAR file, if you have an Android Library as a dependency for your project, you need to:

1. Open the `your-android-library/build.gradle`
2. In the Android Studio menu, go to `Build -> Make Module 'your-android-library'`

Once the Make is done (you'll see a `Build SUCCESSFUL` message), then you are all set up to Run your Android app as you normally do.

> Hint: Add this info into your Readme file, in order for you not to
>   forget once you change environment, like I did just last night before
>   going for a trip.

Comment: Oh my God! You saved me! ;) Great! Thank You a lot!!! But why this is not said in official guide!! :(

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error was due to that .aar was missing so in your case check that your lib mylib-release.aar exists and is found in the debug compileClasspath.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to generate .AAR file by yourself.

go to root project folder -> your proj  -> build -> outputs -> aar -> delete folder or content

go to gradle tools window (usually top right corner of android studio) and get execute task build

your proj-lib-aar -> your proj -> Tasks -> build (double click)